# divisor is equal to zero - aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select 
decode(sal_1,0,null,
(sum(case when date_key between to_char(add_months(sysdate,-12),'YYYYMM') and to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMM') then salary/sal_1  end))) as annual_sal 
from employee
group by emp_key,sal_1;
```

or

```
select 
case when sal_1<>0 then
sum(case when date_key between to_char(add_months(sysdate,-12),'YYYYMM') and to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMM') then salary/sal_1  end)end as annual_sal 
from employee
group by emp_key,sal_1;
```

I'm getting the error 'divisor is equal to zero' with the above queries..where am I going wrong?

Comment: `sal_1` is zero so you get a divide by zero error.

Comment: http://dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01476_divisor_equa_to_zero.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is this one:

```
select sum(
   case when date_key between to_char(add_months(sysdate,-12),'YYYYMM') and to_char (sysdate,'YYYYMM') 
then decode(sal_1,0,NULL, salary/sal_1)  end)
end as annual_sal
from employee
group by emp_key,sal_1;
```

or (better to read in my eyes):

```
select sum(decode(sal_1,0,NULL, salary/sal_1)) as annual_sal
from employee
where date_key between to_char(add_months(sysdate,-12),'YYYYMM') and to_char (sysdate,'YYYYMM') 
group by emp_key,sal_1;
```

Your `CASE` specifies only one `WHEN ... THEN`, why do you use it?

Comment: I have a big query, where this is one such column logic..similar to this I have to perform other where clauses to derive those columns..so I'm using case statement and I cannot use where clause to all of them..

Answer (score 1):

Try this code with where clause

```
select 
case when sal_1<>0 then
sum(case when date_key between to_char(add_months(sysdate,-12),'YYYYMM') and to_char            (sysdate,'YYYYMM') then salary/sal_1  end)end as annual_sal 
from employee
where sal_1 > 0
group by emp_key,sal_1;
```

Comment: this works..Can you explain what I was doing wrong? I was considering only records sal_1<>0 right..
and if I add sal_1>0 in where clause,can I skip the case statement 'case when sal_1<>0'..

Comment: Actually I want to get the results for negative values too..
For example, if I have salary as 430 and sal_1 as -583..then annual_sal should be -0.737..

Comment: remove all the 0 value from our result set.